# REGEX How do I match all of the middle of a sentence?

Tags: regex

I need to regex replace everything in a long string with the first word, new word, last word.  I can match the first and last no problem but I am having all kinds of issues trying to match the middle.
Sample data:

```
tunnel4 connection to router 1 status
gig1/0/1 blah status
g2/0/1 foo bandwidth
```

Output:

```
tunnel4 router1 status
gig1/0/1 router1 status
g2/0/1 router1 bandwidth
```

Match first word works:

```
^([^\s]+)
```

Match last word works:

```
([^\W]+$)
```

The replace would be
`$1 router1 $2` but I can't figure out how to match the middle.  I was trying to match 1st space to last space and I could not seem to get that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
^([^\s]+ ).*( .*)
```

View [demo](https://regex101.com/r/79pMqO/1) here

Comment: I SWEAR I tried that and it failed!  Jeez!  Thank you so much!  I was beating my head against a wall!